# Unable to import fs in Node Server

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node.js-fs

I am running a node server using npm and webpack. Importing three.js as well as it's loaders/controllers works fine, but when I attempt to do the same with 'fs' I get no errors from my terminal running npm but the console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined  
    at Object.fs (main.js:19:1)  
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:93:41)  
    at eval (index.js:5:60)  
    at ./src/index.js (main.js:69:1)  
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:93:41)  
    at main.js:133:37  
    at main.js:135:12
```

I'm struggling to understand why this is happening and have tried every solution I can find (every variation of import eg {fs} vs * as fs, ES6 webpack and CJS webpack, etc.) and they all seem to run into the issue that import fs for some reason calls require.
My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "customizer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -x \"npm run buildrun\"",
    "buildrun": "webpack && npm run server",
    "server": "nodemon --exec python -m http.server",
    "build": "echo 'build' && webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "three": "^0.149.0"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
}
```

and my webpack.config.js is:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  }, 
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      fs: false
    }
  }
};
```

My imports are as follows, with all working except the last:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {fs} from 'fs';
```

Any help would be massively appreciated as I keep uncovering new, fairly recent solutions that just don't work (or are people trying to use fs in the browser, which I don't think applies here)

Comment: You can't access nodejs-only modules from the browser. You can't read files directly from the user computer anyway

Comment: @Konrad I am trying to access files on my node server, my understanding was that importing and using fs was the way to do this? My use case is grabbing files from a folder without hardcoding paths

Comment: The imports you've shown are being bundled with Webpack and running in the browser, no? Three isn't designed to run on a server AFAIK. You would need to run a backend server that exposes the files you want via HTTP, and use fetch to load them into the browser I assume.

Comment: @EvanShortiss Ah, seems circuitous to just read from a local dir but I certainly don't know a better way. I guess I'll just expose them on a server as you said and use Requests, thanks!